# Replacing elements of a matrix

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, replacement

I'm trying to write a program that takes a given matrix `A` of `1`'s and `0`'s and flips a designated amount of `1`'s to `-1`'s.

```
lis1 = ArrayRules[A];
For[i = 1, i < Length[lis1] , i++
   lis2 = RandomChoice[ArrayRules[A], n];
 {a, b} = lis2[[i]];
ReplacePart[lis1, {a,b} -> -1];
```

This obviously doesn't work, and I'm not sure I even need the `For` loop for this, but what syntax do I need specifically to replace the `[i,j]` element of `lis1` with `-[i,j]` of `lis2`?
Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: `ReplacePart[list1, {##} -> -list2[[##]]] & @@@ {{i1, j1}, {i2, j2}}` ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick helper function to do so. It first finds the position of each $1$ in the original matrix using [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html); it then selects $n$ of these positions randomly using [`RandomSample`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSample.html) and replaces their value with $-1$ using [`ReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html):

```
Clear[flipsome]
flipsome[matrix_?MatrixQ, n_Integer] :=
 ReplacePart[matrix, RandomSample[Position[matrix, 1], n] -> -1]
```

Let's generate a random matrix of ones and zeros:

```
(a = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 10}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

.. and use `flipsome` to flip 10 randomly selected $1$s to $-1$:

```
flipsome[a, 10] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'm getting the error ""RandomSample cannot generate a sample of length 2, which is greater \
than the length of the sample set {}. If you want a choice of \
possibly repeated elements from the set, use RandomChoice"" when I try to flip 2 elements, any suggestions?

Comment: Position[matrix, 1] seems to be the problem. I can fix it by substituting Normal[matrix] for matrix, but this is pretty inefficient. I can't figure out how to do this with ArrayRules[matrix].

Comment: @TeeJay That seems to indicate that you are applying `flipsome` to an array that does *not* actually contain any $1$s, so `Position` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
ClearAll[flipF]
flipF = MapAt[-1 &, #, RandomSample[Position[#, 1], #2]] &;
(* or *) flipF = MapAt[-1 &, #, RandomSample[SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"], #2]] &

a = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {9, 9}];
Row[Labeled[MatrixForm@ToExpression@#, #, Top] & /@ {"a", "flipF[a,5]"}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]